# When I terminate process is it terminate thread too?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, process

As I know thread is part of process. If close process do I need close thread manually?
My code:

```
TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0);
CloseHandle(hProcess);
```

I have seen example code where the close process then thread:

```
CloseHandle(l_processInfo.hProcess);
CloseHandle(l_processInfo.hThread);
```

Comment: The "I have seen example code" real-code context is *highly* relevant, and fuel to the fire one shouldn't just grab code and bank on it without having a reasonably firm idea of how it works. That specific pattern is generally (but not exclusively) used when a process is (a) creating another process using CreateProcess, and (b) doesn't care about monitoring/manipulating it thereafter so the control structures maintained in the local process to do so can be closed down.

Comment: Unless your process is terminating itself, it is a good idea to close the handle after calling `TerminateProcess()` since the handle remains valid (still represents OS resources) after the process is terminated.   (Whether using `TerminateProcess()` is a good idea is another question - since the documentation describes some consequences that may be undesirable in some circumstances).    Calling `CloseHandle()` on thread or process handles just means the current process can no longer use that handle to affect the thread/process - the thread and process are not terminated by that action).

Comment: *Closing* a handle to a process does not *terminate* the process. The process terminates only when it calls `ExitProcess()` for itself (ie after its `main()`/`WinMain()` exits), or someone (like you) calls `TerminateProcess()` on it.

Comment: *When I terminate process is it terminate thread too?* - yes, all threads in process will be terminated. *do I need close thread manually* - if you have opened thread handle, you need close it, after you not use it more

Answer (score 2):

According to [How Threads are Terminated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/terminating-a-thread#how-threads-are-terminated),

> A thread executes until one of the following events occurs:
>
> - The thread calls the **ExitThread** function.
> - Any thread of the process calls the **ExitProcess** function.
> - The thread function returns.
> - Any thread calls the **TerminateThread** function with a handle to the thread.
> - Any thread calls the **TerminateProcess** function with a handle to the process.

And

> The **TerminateThread** and **TerminateProcess** functions should be used only
> in extreme circumstances, since they do not allow threads to clean up,
> do not notify attached DLLs, and do not free the initial stack. In
> addition, handles to objects owned by the thread are not closed until
> the process terminates.

Comment: Thx I read your link. It states: "Do not terminate a process unless its threads are in known states. If a thread is waiting on a kernel object, it will not be terminated until the wait has completed. This can cause the application to stop responding." I guess it mean I better teminate all threads before terminate process itself

Comment: No. It doesn't mean that. That won't make any difference.